# Validación de estructura de los archivos dentro de un SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Actualmente tengo el siguiente flujo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información de la Izquierda, viene de un archivo llamado Compras.asl, el flujo lo hace correctamente, lo que necesito hacer es validar la estructura del archivo, que tenga dicha estructura correcta, mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo realizar dicha validación de la metadata sin tener que realizar storeprocedure? Quiero hacerlo dentro del flujo como tal, ¿Es posible realizar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un Conditional Split o un Script Component y hacer el código en C# o VB.net